# Wordpress create lists of favorites for users

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, custom-post-type, custom-fields

I have to create lists of favorites products in woocommerce.

First I've created a new custom post type to manage my products list.
Now I need to add my products list to my custom type but I don't know how to do this.

The final result will be a page listing all my lists for a user contains all added products by user.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: You'd better use categories/keywords or create a custom taxonomy as a starting point to create your lists. This will allow you to add products to specific lists in the backend. You can then use the category/keywords or taxonomy URLs to display a list's content. As for a front-end UI allowing users to create and add products to lists, I'm suprised that I can't find any plugin solution for this... I'm still looking!

Comment: I've created my lists in mata_user_data and manage them in my-account custom tab. :)
Thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 1):

I found a pretty comprehensive (paid) plugin by WooCommerce that does exactly this: **WooCommerce Wishlists**. I haven't tried it.

> WooCommerce Wishlists allows guests and customers to create and add products to an unlimited number of Wishlists. From birthdays to weddings and everything in between, WooCommerce Wishlists is a welcome addition to any WooCommerce store.

Plugin link: https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-wishlists/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer but i've needed to make my own plugin.
WC Wishlist allow you to make only one list ;)

After some works i've found a solution with meta_user_data to manage my lists.

```
 public function action_create_favorite_list(){
 
 

  if( ! is_user_logged_in() ) :
    return;
  endif;

  $list = new stdClass();
  $list->name = $_POST["list_name"];
  $list->items = array();

  $fav = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'user_'.get_current_user_id().'_favlist', true);
  if(empty($fav))
  {
    add_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'user_'.get_current_user_id().'_favlist', array());
    $fav = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'user_'.get_current_user_id().'_favlist', true);
  }

  array_push($fav,$list);

  update_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'user_'.get_current_user_id().'_favlist', $fav);

  wp_send_json($fav);
  wp_die();
}
```